# How can I remove empty dataframes from a series of dataframes in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

In python, I have a pandas series filled with pandas dataframes. However, sometimes an empty dataframe occurs in the series. Because they are causing trouble, I want to filter them out. I the following: `serie[not serie.empty]`, `serie[!serie.empty]`, but both is giving me errors. As alternative, I first replaced the empty data frames by 0, and then tried this: `serie[serie != 0]`, but this is ambigu according to the error. Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A series of DataFrames?

You can check if a dataframe is empty with df.empty, so you could do

```
serie[[not df.empty for df in serie]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A pandas Series has no `empty` method. You can use `map` to ask each element of the series to return its `empty` attribute:

```
from operator import attrgetter
serie[~serie.map(attrgetter('empty'))]
```